# <Exclude> tag in AppScanConfig.xml is not excluding the directory during App Scan

Tags: security, bluemix-app-scan

I followed the [App Scan Doc](https://help.hcltechsw.com/appscan/ASoC/src_irx_gen_config.html#src_irx_gen_config__behavior) to exclude node_modules directory when scanning a project but it doesn't work

AppScanConfig.xml

```
 <Configuration>
  <Targets>
    <Target path=".">
      <Include>*</Include>
      <Exclude>image/src/node_modules/</Exclude>
    </Target>
  </Targets>
</Configuration>
```

What am I missing in the configuration ?

Comment: You managed to solve that? Cause im also not able to exclude folders/files.

Comment: @nisanarz The support team told me you can only exclude folders that contain source code files not open source ones. In my case the scan will pick up node_modules folder even if it's excluded in AppScanConfig.xml because it consists of open source files. I wasn't totally satisfied with the answer but haven't done any further digging yet.